Play Store shows me older version instead of new internal test version
I already used internal test and works well but I uploaded new version in store and when I try to install app using link in "Testers" tab. Play store shows me older version.
My app seems to be ready for the download cause state is "Accessible for internal testers" with green checked icon
What I tried

My phone is up-to-date
Turn the phone off and on
Clear Google Play Store cache
Tried to download app in another phone

What I miss ?

Are you mentioning about Internal Testing or Internal App Sharing? If you are mentioning about app sharing then you will get new link when you uploaded new build version. If you are mentioning about Internal testing, then you have to wait, play store will update your Internal testing version to newer, then you can use your existing link.

Thank you for your reply, I will wait because it's for internal testing
